# How to prevent href default behavior from changing URL name Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my component, I've installed a dependency called vue2-smooth-scroll that allows me to scroll to my target element based on its id. This is the code to achieve that:

```
<a href="#test" class="mouse-icon" @click.prevent="preventDefault" v-smooth-scroll>
```

I was able to scroll to the element, with an id of #test as shown in the following code

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

However, I notice that the id "test" will be appended at the end of the URL. how do you stop that from happening? For example,

http://localhost:8081/#/test

Comment: try 
```<div><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.scroll(0,1);">click here</a></div>```

Comment: Hi @MayuriPansuriya How do you scroll to a specific element based on its ID with your code?

Comment: So what's your `preventDefault` method? Because you're calling this method with @click?

Comment: The location hash is actually [set by `vue2-smooth-scroll`](https://github.com/Yuliang-Lee/vue2-smooth-scroll/blob/3353882/src/index.js#L70). You probably have to modify the plugin itself.

Comment: @tony19 How do I modify it? I am not sure what the code does.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent href default behavior from changing URL. You can listen for the click event then call `preventDefault` or in VueJS you can add prevent click modifier.

It would be like:

```
<a href='#test' @click.prevent>Anchor</a>
```

But this will not work for you case because `vue2-smooth-scroll` intentionally set hash on the URL. As you can see in the source code on line [48](https://github.com/Yuliang-Lee/vue2-smooth-scroll/blob/master/src/index.js#L48) and line [70](https://github.com/Yuliang-Lee/vue2-smooth-scroll/blob/master/src/index.js#L70).

So you can dirty set it back but it needs to be after animation finished.

```
<template>
  <a href='#test' @click='setUrlBack' v-smooth-scroll>Anchor</a>
</template>

<script>
  setUrlBack () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      history.replaceState(null, null, ' ')
    }, 550) // animation duration + a little delay
  }
</script>
```

Well, this is very bad idea.

Another option is ask the author to add support something like `no-hash` property.

Or just create your own plugin file then copy the code, paste and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything from the `#` on (in the URL) is known as the `hash`.  This is used by the browser for navigation and input parameters.  The hash can be changed by the browser without submitting a new request to the server.

Most likely it is how SmoothScroll is implemented, and is required.  If you scroll to 2 links, you can use forward and back to navigate, or create a bookmark to a link.

Even without the plugin, browsers and URLs use the `hash` when navigating to internal links.

Unless you have a really good reason to remove it, I would just live with it.